# How do I attach a click listener to a datatable in DT and Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a Shiny app where I try to attach a `click` listener to a `datatable` row.

Here's my code:

```
require(DT)
require(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        titlePanel("Data Explorer")
    ),
    fluidRow(
        column(
            DT::dataTableOutput("listTable"),
            width = 4
        ),
        column(
            width = 8
        )
    )
)

get.data <- function() {
    res <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))
    return(res)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$listTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        showModal(modalDialog("Fetching Data..."))
        dt <- datatable(get.data(), 
                        rownames = FALSE, 
                        options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,
                                       selection = 'none',
                                       callback = JS("$('#listTable tbody').on('click.dt', 'tr', function() { console.log('foo'); })")))
        removeModal()
        return(dt)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

All the examples I found via googling have used the implicitly provided `table` variable to find the root element, but when I try to do that, I just get a `ReferenceError: table is not defined`.

So I've used a direct JQuery search instead. When I use `console.log('foo')` as the callback, it works fine. But when I try to attach a listener as I do above, it doesn't attach. When I copy-paste that exact same code into my Firefox console on the page, it works.

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`callback` is an argument of the `datatable` function, it does not belong to the `options` list. So you have to do like this:

```
dt <- datatable(
  get.data(), 
  rownames = FALSE, 
  callback = JS("table.on('click', 'tr', function() { alert('foo'); })"),
  options = list(
    autoWidth = TRUE,
    selection = 'none'
  )
)
```